# Google Sheets: Convert currency based on date provided in cell

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list of transactions in different currencies and wonder if it's possible to automate conversion based on transaction date provided in a cell. See image below for visual representation:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work if your date is in A3. Be careful of the date 1-MAR will default to the current year if no year is entered. Index is used to return only the rate:

```
=index(GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:EURUSD","close",A3),2,2)
```

Comment: If this works for you, would you please approve the answer. Thanks

Comment: I tried, but apparently I don't have enough points for it to be displayed.